# HTML List / Menu - Can the width be changed automatically? (for hovering/slidedown)

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I am using an html list for a vertical dropdown menu with various submenus. Each navigation point is a list item in an unordered list.

Each of the sub-navigation elements are in a subsequent list in another list which are initially hidden.

When a top element is hovered, the list slides down. The problem is that the top item takes the full width of the widest item, so it 'triggers' when the mouse is actually outside of the text.

[image: Extra width]

I tried targeting the text in the top item more specifically with a span, but then the problem is once the mouse leaves the text, the menu slides up while hovering over the new items.

Is there a way to make this top navigation item not have the full width of all its child elements?

**EDIT:**

Actually I finally managed to fix it - The problem was that I had declared a width on the entire list because without it, the slidedown was causing the menu to 'jump' at the bottom after it was sliding down, I suppose the text was 'unwrapping' itself or something. With the width applied to the subnavigation items instead, the list doesn't pop and the 'target' area is accurately only the top point.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your navigation looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Nav Point 1
        <ul>
            <li>navigation item 1</li>
            <li>navigation item 2</li>
            <li>navigation item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Nav Point 2
        <ul>
            ....
```

Because the navigation items are within the structure of the nav point, I think the size of point is going to be determined by the item, assuming it's larger.  To accomplish what you want, I think you'll have to consider a different structure.

Perhaps you could work with two separate lists of lists?  The first list is the top level nav points, the second with navigation items.  You'd use a script and CSS to hide the second list and position the items to display below the corresponding top level navigation.  Your script would reveal and hide the menus as called for in the appropriate locations.  Your script may need to break out the lists of navigation items into separate structures if you want to show more than one at a time (ie, if menus "linger" after your mouse moves out).

It's not as simple as the typical "list of lists" structure, but it's also a more sophisticated display, so you pay in complexity.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, but I finally managed to figure it out while keeping the existing structure - You are exactly correct though, that is the structure of the menu I was using! The key was to apply width to the nested list instead of the top items.